# How to compare only structure (ignore values) of two JSON objects by jackson library?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I use library org.codehaus.jackson. I have 2 JSON object. First object I read from file `hello.json`. Second I generate automatically.
First:

```
{
  "name": "some value",
  "date": 1480971600000
}
```

Second:

```
{
  "name": "some value",
  "date": 1480971600777
}
```

They have the same structure but different values of `"date"` property. I want to compare only structure of these objects ignoring values. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have fixed set of JSON formats then easiest way would be to create JSON Schema and validate with it. Something like:

```
JsonNode data = JsonLoader.fromString(jsonData);
JsonNode schema = JsonLoader.fromString(jsonSchema);

JsonSchemaFactory factory = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault();
JsonValidator validator = factory.getValidator();

ProcessingReport report = validator.validate(schema, data);
```

Comment: What's jsonData? What's jsonSchema? please provide an example